# Can't slide the menu after adding footer to navigation drawer

Tags: android

I added a footer to the navigation drawer in Android Studio 2.1.3 but I can't slide the menu.

It is always open and it covers the main screen, also it hides the hamburger icon.

I searched but could not find how to solve this issue.

The activity main xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/spacer_to_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <include layout="@layout/nav_footer_main">
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the the footer xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fb"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/twitter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/youtube"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/youtube"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the screenshot my app

[image: Main Screenshot of the App]

Comment: Try to set the gravity of the NavigationView to "left" instead of "right"

Comment: thanks very much for your quick answer, i tried before but it doesn't helped me, thanks